# Temperature distribution in a current carrying conductor

Tags: electricity, electric-circuits, conductors, thermal-conductivity, thermoelectricity

A rod of uniform cross section and composition is connected across a battery. Let the middle part of the rod(when divided into three equal parts) is heated uniformly.
A book says that the temperature in all the three regions will become non uniform and the location of the highest temperature is in the middle region nearer to the right end.

Why is it so?? According to my thinking the middle part must have uniform distribution and it must gradually decrease on both sides??

Does the temperature of a conductor increase in the direction of flow of current?? If so why??

Comment: What is the direction of the applied voltage.There should be more heat produced near the negative side of the battery

Comment: @RishabhJain - ummm... Why? Explain, please.

Comment: I am also eager to read your reasoning @RishabhJain.

Comment: @thermomagneticcondensedboson Expanding better on my answer, the resistance curve of the rod will be somewhat like a triangle with the maximum lying in the middle(highest temperature). Now, the electrons traveling from the negative side will see an upward slope of resistance, i.e the electrons in the front have a lower relaxation time. In the other end, the electrons will see a downward slope, i.e, the electrons in the front have a higher relaxtion time. Intuitively, you can see that the average collission will be more in the first part. However, I still need to prove it mathematically.

Comment: @JonCuster Please see my answer and then the new comment.

Answer (score 0):

Electrons carry KE as well as charge. Good electrical conductors tend also to be good thermal conductors. So there is a small net flow of thermal energy in the direction of the drift velocity. This happens regardless of whether the central section of the wire is being heated.

Without any flow of electrons the maximum temperature would be in the middle of the central section. With the flow of electrons added the maximum temperature will be "downstream" of the maximum when no current flows  - ie very slightly towards the +ve terminal.

Comment: This is not quite correct. It is true that good electrical conductors tend to be good thermal conductors, especially in metals and heavily doped semiconductors. The result is that the thermal conductivity κ has a high contribution from electrons (compared to that of the phonons). But this does not mean that there will be a flow of heat in the direction of the drift velocity, this part is wrong. I have written down an answer that explains the asymmetry the asker was trying to explain and an expression that gives the heat's direction (heat flux, more precisely).

Answer (score 0):

The book is wrong in that the statement is not necessarily true. Nevertheless, it is right in that there can be an asymmetry.

**The short answer is that the thermoelectric effect is responsible for the temperature distribution asymmetry.**

The long answer is the following:

In a homogeneous and isotropic current-carrying wire at steady-state, the temperature has to obey the heat equation (1D to keep things simple and ignoring radiation and convection which can be partly circumvented experimentally anyway.) $\kappa \frac{d^2 T}{dx^2}+\rho J^2 -\mu J\frac{dT}{dx}= 0$. I am not yet specifying the boundary conditions.

The first term arises from conservation of energy + Fourier's law. It's essentially the heat conduction. $\kappa$ is the thermal conductivity.

The second term is the Joule heat. $\rho$ is the resistivity and $J$ is the current density. If you were to stop here, the equation would have symmetric solutions unless you assume that, for example, either $\kappa$ or $\rho$ have a non linear temperature dependence in the temperature range the experiment is done. One way to see that, is that if you change $x$ by $-x$ in the equation, it stays the same. And your boundary conditions are symmetric, so there is no reason why the solution would be asymmetric.

Anyway, the third term is the Thomson heat, caused by the Thomson effect. $\mu$ is the Thomson coefficient, and can have either sign. This term causes an asymmetry, regardless of the temperature dependence of the other parameters (you can just assume them constant). One way to see that is to start from a sketch of $T(x)$ when only the Joule heating (and Fourier conduction) are assumed. That plot is symmetric about the middle of the wire and has a maximum right at the center, as you correctly guessed. It looks similar to a parabola in the center region. However, the Thomson heat ($Q_T = -\mu\vec J \cdot \nabla T)$ changes sign about the center of the wire. This is because the temperature gradient, which in about half the wire points in the direction of the current (or against it), points in the opposite direction in the other half, while $\vec J$ maintains its direction. Thus, everywhere in the volume of the wire, there will be a cooling in about half the wire due to the Thomson heat, and a heating in the other half (this is in addition of the Joule heat that occurs through the whole volume too, as the equation describes). But if you focus in a very tiny region near the middle (the temperature gradient is very small, and so is the Thomson heat), you will see that adding heat (i.e. rising the temperature slightly) on a side (of the parabolic $T(x)$) and reducing it on the other side, actually shifts the position of maximum temperature. This is what the Thomson heat does.

The problem with the book is that it assumes that $\mu$ has a particular sign and that it must be so. This is wrong, in reality $\mu$ can have either sign, and if you consider a wire whose material has an opposite Thomson coefficient sign, the maximum temperature will be reached between the middle and the left end of the middle region.

**Extra information.** It turns out that $\mu=T\frac{\partial S}{\partial T}$ where $S$ is the Seebeck coefficient and whose sign is (somewhat) an indicator of whether a material has a majority of p (holes) or n (electrons) charge carriers. So even in the case where we're sure that electrons are the ones moving, $\mu$ can have either sign, and so the maximum temperature can be reached at either side of the center. This goes against @sammy gerbil's answer. The basis of his answer is correct in that good electrical conductors tend to be good thermal conductors, but this only means that $\kappa$ will have a non negligible, or even dominant, contribution from the electrons as opposed to the phonons. This does not imply that heat flows in the direction of the current, this part is wrong. Heat's direction is determined by the direction of $-\kappa \nabla T + ST \vec J$ where S is the Seebeck coefficient and can have either sign (or even zero).

Answer (score 0):

I can explain it in a simple layman terms:
Resistance of the middle part is more since temperature is more. Now electrons while flowing from negative to positive faces an increase in resistance/obstruction at point D [since it is given that the rod is uniformly heated in section CD], therefore while flowing, the electrons get slightly accumulated near the point D. Now electrons have charge, KE and energy due to which temperature near point D is maximum. If we arrange in ascending order of temperature, then we get :
D>C>B>A
Since CD point is heated, it ought to have max temperature... distribution will obviously be non uniform due to varying resistance/charge accumulation....

Comment: This is incorrect. If you ignore thermoelectric effects and only consider Joule heat (as you do in your answer), and keep the ends of the wire at a fixed temperature, then it is true that for metals (not semiconductors!), the middle is going to have a higher temperature because of the Joule heat if you use a current source. However, if you solve the heat equation including the Joule term, you will get a solution that is symmetric. In other words, you cannot explain the asymmetry this way.

Answer (score -1):

Try to think in terms of what is current.It is just the average motion of electrons in a wire ,or a resistor or whatever.Now ,the current actually depends on the drift velocity of the electrons, i.e relaxation time of the electrons. We know and can easily understand that the relaxation time decreases with high temperature and the number of collisions will increase first from where the electrons are travelling that i suppose in your question is the right region .The increase in collisions will produce more heat in the region and the current will decrease due to increasing resistance.

Now, less motion of electron's will be there at the place at the left side which will cause less heating .But the net effects will be small.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention the direction applied voltage. The positive terminal is to the left

Comment: It seems like you believe that the system will be frozen in a state of transient rather than steady-state, in that the rod will have a memory of which side the electrons started to feel the E field (which was established at almost the speed of light, i.e. almost instantly for all practical purposes). It doesn't make sense.